# Fetching data from thingspeak using retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I want to fetch data from a field in my channel thingspeak to android using retrofit, I has been try but the code it's not work, this is my endpoint

```
 Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.thingspeak.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

API interface

```
@GET("channels/637542/fields/1.json?results=2")
Call<List<Ultrasonic>> getData();
```

POJO class

```
   package com.iot.parkthink.parkthink.POJOClass;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Ultrasonic {

        @SerializedName("created_at")
        @Expose
        private String createdAt;
        @SerializedName("entry_id")
        @Expose
        private Integer entryId;
        @SerializedName("field1")
        @Expose
        private String field1;

        private String image;

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
            return createdAt;
        }

        public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
            this.createdAt = createdAt;
        }

        public Integer getEntryId() {
            return entryId;
        }

        public void setEntryId(Integer entryId) {
            this.entryId = entryId;
        }

        public String getField1() {
            return field1;
        }

        public void setField1(String field1) {
            this.field1 = field1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead Of

```
@GET("channels/637542/fields/1.json?results=2")
Call<List<Ultrasonic>> getData();
```

you can Use

```
@GET("channels/637542/fields/1.json")

    Call<List<Ultrasonic>> getData(@Query("results") int results);
```

and call it

```
getData(2)
```

Comment: I got this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "channels/637542/fields/1.json" does not contain "{results}". (parameter #1)

Comment: sorry i Edit my answer